# Sub Woofers not working on HP-DV6 on upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp

I have a HP-DV6165tx.

In 11.10 to enable the sub woofers I had added this line to the

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file

options snd-hda-intel model=ref
```

After upgrading to 12.04 I had no sound.

So I changed it to

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp
```

I ended with hp after a lot of trial and errors looking at the

```
 /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz file
```

Now my speakers work but the 2 sub woofers are still not working. Any workaround to this?

Comment: Try this http://www.smittix.co.uk/beats-audio-subwoofer-not-working-correctly-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 1):

My hp touchsmart sound is coming up using this

```
options snd-hda-intel model=touchsmart
```